# drupal module defines front page using hook_menu...What does it need to return?

Tags: hooks

I am using hook menu to define the front page (/front) and I found out if I return '' it renders the theme with all the blocks.

If I return content, is that what gets rendered into the Main Content block? What is the purpose of returning data from this function?

```
function dc_mad_marchness_menu()
{
    $items['front'] = array(
        'title' => 'Home',
        'page callback' => 'dc_mad_marchness_front',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}


function dc_mad_marchness_front()
{
    return '';
}
```

Comment: the answer for you first question is yes

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you return either a string or a [render array](http://drupal.org/node/930760) from a page callback function, it will be rendered in the main content region on the front end (well, under normal circumstances anyway. There are possible exceptions).

There's an in-depth description of `page callback` in the [`hook_menu()` docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) which is a bit long to reproduce here. I'd recommend giving it a read through.